# Vue.js history mode Custom 404 Page

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've made an Application of Admin Template with Vue.js
URL: http://vuejsadmin.com/

Everything seems fine. But I cann't configure 404 page on my VPS Hosting. Because if I go to direct URL like http://vuejsadmin.com/components/buttons
then nginx 404 is showing. I want to show my Template's 404 Page.

How can I customize it with my Template's 404 Page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the file where your routes are, you need to define a path with '*' wildcard to your 404 component:

```
...
routes: [
  // Other paths and their children...
  ...
  // Any other paths must return your 404Component now
  { path: '*', component: 404Component },
]
```

Comment: I've changed it like <br> <pre>{ path: '*', redirect: { name: 'Page404', component: Page404 }  }</pre> but still doesn't work on Live URL: http://vuejsadmin.com/components/buttons